# Last element of JAVA char array is not replaced

Tags: java, arrays, replace, char

In a  JAVA  'char[] a' , I want to replace all the charachters by 'q', except 'x' and 'y'. I tried it by the JAVA code below. It works but fails to replace the last character. I need help to complete the replacement.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
       char[] a ={'x','y','z','x','y','r','b'};

       for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){

        if ( a[i]=='x') {
                i=i+1;
            if ( a[i]=='y') {
                   i=i+1;
                   a[i]='q';
            } 
                System.out.println(a);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code 'll only change each first char directly after 'x''y' to 'q'. your last char doesn't validate to true according to those rules

Comment: You should neven manupulate the counter of your loop. I think there is the porblem.

Comment: How can this work? The code does not do what you described. What the code does is the following: "For all `x` followed by a `y`, replace the following character with `q`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check whether the current char (at index `i`) is not `x` or `y`. If it is one of there characters the for loop continues as usual and checks the next character.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
   char c = a[i]; //get current char
   if(c != 'x' && c != 'y'){ //check if it is a x or y
      a[i] = 'q' //replace current char
   }
}
```

Comment: The code you provided has given needed result. But being new to programming I am still confused why my code version failed. Can you give a hint for its failure?

Comment: Why `char c = a[i];`?

Comment: @Braffdev: please add some explanation to your solution of hopw it solves the problem and what the OP was missing or getting wrong.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind - for clarity

Answer (score 3):

replace everything within your for by:

```
if ( a[i] != 'x' && a[i] != 'y' ){ a[i] = 'q'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to inspect your code, but i will show you a way how u can accomplish your goal.

```
  char[] a = {'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'r', 'b'};
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == 'x' || a[i] == 'y') {
      continue;
    } else {
      a[i] = 'q';
    }
  }
  System.out.println(a);
```

The keyword continue in java skips actual iteration and goes to the next one.

Answer (score 0):

Your code inside the loop will only replace by `q` any char that follows sequence `x, y`.  One way to replace all chars except `x` and `y` is can change your loop to:

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){

    if ( a[i]!='x' && a[i] != 'y') {
       a[i]='q';
    } 
}

System.out.println(a);
```

Also note that your `System.out.println` is seemingly in a wrong place and will not output anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

As Jens points out, don't ever modify the loop counter.
Java doesn't care about this, but you may. Assuming we're in the first iteration, therefore:

```
    int i = 0;

    if ( a[i]=='x') { // i is still 0
            i=i+1;    // i becomes 1
        if ( a[i]=='y') { // OOPS, i is 1 here. so this is a[1] and therefore 'y'
               i=i+1;
               a[i]='q';
        } 
            System.out.println(a);
     }
```

In a `for` loop, you can use `continue;` to skip the rest of the loop and jump to the next iteration.

Remember that the exit condition of a `for` gets only evaluated once: at the beginning of the `for` block.

Answer (score 0):

surely instead of:

```
if (a[i] == 'x'){i=i+1;
if (a[i] == 'y'){i=i+1;
a[i] = 'q';
}
System.out.println(a);
}
```

you can do:

```
if (a[i] != 'x' || a[i] != 'y'){
   a[i] = q;
System.out.println(a);
}
```